# arrayindex length too small even with title change

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, indexing

having a bit of trouble with my list array it was originally 4 items long from a tutorial, then i tried to play around with it and expand it in size by entering more titles and images but i get the following 
**error in logcat:**

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException = length=4; index=4
```

**Here is the code:**

```
package org.iimed.www;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.iimed.www.R;
import org.iimed.www.CustomListViewAdapter;
import org.iimed.www.RowItem;

public class ImageTextListViewActivity extends Activity implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Penicillins",
            "Cephalosporins", "Monobactams", "Carbapenems","Macrolides","Tetracyclines",};

    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
            "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
            "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
            "Mixed Fruits" };

    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,
            R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, R.drawable.antibiotic_buton,R.drawable.antibiotic_buton, };

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screj);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

seeing as < = titles.length, shouldn't the increase in "titles" increase the length?or is the listview in the layout itself too small?Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only 4 descriptions and the tiles and images array are of length 6. Add more descriptions

```
public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
        "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
        "Mixed Fruits" };
```

Comment: Righto thanks all of you, so the all the fields entered (images,descriptions,titles) must be equal? some items can not have no description?

Comment: If you want items to have no descriptions, simply set the value to empty strings for those items.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
```

This is the problem. You are trying to access the index `titles.length` in the final iteration, which is not allowed. The max accessible index in an array is always `arrayLength - 1`. That's because indexes in an array are `0-based`. They start with the index `0` and end at the index, `array.length - 1`.

Change your `for` to something like this and it'll work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) { // without the equals symbol
```

Also, your `description` array seems to have only 4 elements, compared to the `titles` array which has 6. Once the above change is done, you'll get the AIOOBE because the description array has just 4 elements. Add a couple more elements, so that all arrays has equal elements, incase you want to use a single loop for all.

If some items don't have a description, provide a blank string or a null in the array

```
String[] descriptions = new String[] {
    "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
    "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
    "Mixed Fruits", null, "" }; // Either blank string, or null value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the items in the array descriptions is 4 and you are trying to access descriptions[4] an above. because the titles array contains 6 items and you are using the length of titles in the loop. Array index is start from 0-(size-1), so just cross check that in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `title` array (length of 6) is longer than your `description` array (length of 4).  So when you iterate on the length of the `title` array and try to access the index 4 of your `description` array, you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

This is where problem appears:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}
```

To fix it, you probably need to add two new items in your `description` array to match the number of items in your `titles` and `images` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your for loop because the size of titles and description array is not same

```
for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
         if(i<=descriptions.length)
        {
         RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
         rowItems.add(item);
       }else
       {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], "");
        rowItems.add(item);
      }
     }
```